# Drop user after granted privilege on Object with grant option

Tags: object, privileges, sql-grant

If user A gives the following privileges to user B on a table, then userB has dropped.

user A : Grant select on emp to userB with GRANT OPTION;
userB : Grant select on emp to userc;

DROP user userB cascade;

Will the userC still have rights to select the emp table ?

What is the outcome of the following? Im a bit confused on this.